# Symfony Assert\Expression compare entity property with current users property

Tags: symfony, assert

Is it possible to get current authenticated user object in symfony Assert\Expression ?

I want to use something like

```
#[Assert\Expression(
    this.getType() != user.getType()",
    message: 'Invalid type'
)]
```

I tried but getting an error

```
Variable \"user\" is not valid around position 60 for expression
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to get the current authenticated user directly from your entity.

In this case, you should create a custom constraint & validator as explained here : https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html#creating-the-constraint-class.

You could create a `HasValidType` and `HasValidTypeValidator` in which you can inject the `Security` component of Symfony and perform a `$this->security->getUser()` to get the current authenticated user.